# Add a new line to the end of a JtextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a text area with some text in it and I want to add some lines to it again, (the first lines + the other lines that I want to add) but it doesn't work.

The way I'm doing it right now erases the old text and shows just the new lines.

Comment: consider a very simple code for showing some lines in the text area

Comment: Is this about java or javascript?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Instead of using `JTextArea.setText(String text)`, use [`JTextArea.append(String text)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String)).

> Appends the given text to the end of the document. Does nothing if the model is null or the string is null or empty.

This will add text on to the end of your `JTextArea`.

Another option would be to use `getText()` to get the text from the `JTextArea`, then manipulate the String (add or remove or change the String), then use `setText(String text)` to set the text of the `JTextArea` to be the new String.

Comment: Don't forget to add \n to actually add new line

Answer (score 14):

Are you using `JTextArea`'s `append(String)` method to add additional text?

```
JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea("Hello, World\n", 20, 20);
txtArea.append("Goodbye Cruel World\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to create a new line or wrap in your TextArea you have to add \n (newline) after the text.

```
TextArea t = new TextArea();
t.setText("insert text when you want a new line add \nThen more text....);
setBounds();
setFont();
add(t);
```

This is the only way I was able to do it, maybe there is a simpler way but I havent discovered that yet.