# Generating random numbers from data

Tags: java

I have this ArrayList of data filled with numbers from a file I open which I would like to be able to generate random numbers from it by entering the size of the sample and the number of samples I want. So I have the following...

```
private JTextField jtfN = new JTextField();// where i enter the amount of samples
private JTextField jtfn = new JTextField();// where i enter the size of samples
private ArrayList< Double> data = new ArrayList< Double>();
```

I have two text fields one named jtfn(size of sample) and one jtfN(amount of samples)
which are where I enter the values. Then from that i have a button named jbtnGenerate whch when i click I want it to generate random numbers from data with the jtfn and jtfN entered above then putting it in a TextArea named jta

That's where I open files and add the numbers into data

```
if( jfc.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {

String file = jfc.getSelectedFile().getPath();
String line = null;
String[] ch;

try {   
    FileReader fr = new FileReader( file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    data.clear();
    while( (ligne=br.readLine())!=null ) {
        ch = line.split( ";" );
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
            data.add( Double.parseDouble(ch[i]) );  
        }                       
    }

    br.close();             
}
catch( IOException ioe ) {
}
```

}

That's my listener for the button "generate" where I would like for the actions to happen.

```
       jbtnGenerer.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae ) {

            try {                   

             int sampSize = Integer.parseInt(jtfn.getText());
             int nSamples = Integer.parseInt(jtfN.getText());

            double samps[][] = new double[nSamples][sampSize];

            for(int i = 0 ; i < nSamples; i++){
                for(int j = 0 ; j < sampSize; j++)
                    samps[i][j] = (Double) data.toArray()[ rng.nextInt() % data.size() ];
              }


                jta.append(samps.toString());

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            }
        }

    });
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I definitely wouldn't name your variables that way... very easy to create bugs.

Comment: I am completely distracted by wondering what jtfn and jtfN mean.

Comment: Just for clarification purposes, it looks like you want to take N samples of n doubles from data, right?

Comment: @Peter, I would guess Java text field, with `n` and `N` being the variables that they capture. But that doesn't make it right...

Comment: They are textfields where I enter the values. jtfn is where I set the size of the samples and jtfN is where I set the amount of samples i wanna take. And these numbers are take from data which is an ArrayList of doubles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as true random in code, but there are pseudo-random number generators. In order generate integers and create groups of samples, you'll need to create a Random object. You'll have to import it first:

```
    import java.util.Random;
```

Then, you'll have to create it and give it a seed in your function. The most commonly used seed is the current time in milliseconds:

```
    Random rng = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );
```

My guess is that you'd want to first parse the input, so something like

```
    int sampSize;
    int nSamples;
    if( !jtfn.getText().isEmpty() )
     sampSize = Integer.parseInt(jtfn.getText());
    if( !jtfN.getText().isEmpty() )
     nSamples = Integer.parseInt(jtfN.getText());
```

Then you'll have to make something to hold your samples. A 2D array would work fine.

```
    double samps[][] = new double[nSamples][sampSize];
```

From there, you'll need to populate your array of sample groups. A single loop works fine, but for readability's sake, here's a nested for-loop:

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nSamples; i++){
      for(int j = 0 ; j < sampSize; j++)
        samps[i][j] = data.get( rng.nextInt(data.size()) );
    }
```

Where rand() is the RNG function your language would use. From there, you'll have an N x n sized array filled with samples.

Comment: When I try to add that it gives me that data[ rand() % data.length ]; length cannot be resolved or is not a field also I can't parse them into an int cause they're text fields

Comment: I updated my answer. This of course assumes that data is already populated with doubles.

Edit: Judging by the updated question, it looks like you do.

Comment: I added more information in my main answer and yes when I open the file it adds doubles into data but for some reason this one is giving me errors
 samps[i][j] = data.toArray()[ rand() % data.length ];

Comment: I tried to cast it to a double and change the length to size samps[i][j] =  (Double) data.toArray()[ rand() *data.size() ]; the error is that rand is undefined for the new type actionlistener

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated again to discuss the `Random` object and how to generate integers from it. Hope that's useful. `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the current time in milliseconds.

Comment: I also tried with the samps[i][j] = (Double) data.toArray()[ (int) Math.random() * data.size() ]; but its giving a Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" then it says the error is at the   int sampSize = Integer.parseInt(jtfn.getText());
    int nSamples = Integer.parseInt(jtfN.getText());

Comment: Use the `Random` object as I stated above. The `Integer.parseInt()` issue is stemming from there not being any input for the text boxes to parse. You will need to surround it with a try-catch statement or precede it with an if-statement that checks the length of the strings in your text boxes. Something like `if(!jtfn.getText().isEmpty())` will do.

Comment: Yea, that's what I had done added a try catch for it. For some reason when i enter the values lets say 50 and 200 and click generate it doesn't show anything in my text area. Edit: I loaded the filed before and when I did then click generate it's giving me an index out of bounds error "Exception in thread 'AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -47217
 at Intervalleur$3.actionPerformed(Intervalleur.java:166)'

Comment: For that, you can find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088016/add-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-jtextarea). To add an entire group of answers, you'll just have to use a for-loop which loops from 0 to n of whichever group you desire. As an example, `for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) jta.append(samps[0][i].toString());` appends the first group in the array to the TextArea.

Comment: Oh I know that. What I mean is that when I go select open a text file then enter say 50,200 clicking generate its giving the out of bounds exception to `samps[i][j] = (Double) data.toArray()[ rng.nextInt() % data.size() ];`

Comment: Try simplifying the random element selector to `data.get(rng.nextInt(data.size()));` I'll update it above.

Comment: I tried now what it does is sends me this in the text area `[[D@fdbc27`

Comment: That's usually the output if you try to print out an array rather than the elements inside the array. What do you have in the `jta.append()` method?

Comment: `jta.append(samps.toString()+"\n");` I tried doing a for for it but it tells me cannot invoke toString() on the primitive double `for(int i = 0 ; i < data.size() ; i++ ) jta.append(samps[0][i].toString());` Edit: I fixed the for `for(int i = 0 ; i < data.size() ; i++ ) 
jta.append(String.valueOf(samps[0][i])+"\n");` but after it runs it gives me index out of bounds for the append part

Comment: Accoring to the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766318/converting-double-to-string) , try `for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) jta.append(String.valueOf(samps[0][i]));` to convert doubles to strings. That'll get you your first group of n samples. You can set up a nested for-loop to get the rest.

Comment: I made this `for(int i = 0 ; i < samps.length  ; i++ )  {
      
         for(int j = 0 ; j < samps.length  ; j++ )
        jta.append(String.valueOf(samps[i][j])+"\n");
       
        
       }` but it's giving me an out of bounds exception for `jta.append(String.valueOf(samps[i][j])+"\n");` I feel like my <samps.length isn't right, but I can't seem to figure what to put as that

Comment: I think this worked was confusing things `for(int i = 0 ; i < nSamples  ; i++ )  {      
         for(int j = 0 ; j < sampSize  ; j++ )
        jta.append(String.valueOf(samps[i][j])+"\n");
       
        
       }`

Comment: Is there a way to format the answer to 6 decimals only I tried using string.format but it doesn't work