# How do I read in from a file and display in a textfield/label in a GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, exception, jlabel, jtextfield

I have a text file with a list of names in. I am trying to create a GUI and then read in the text from the file into the GUI and display it in a textfield/label/anything. I can create the GUI and read in the code, but do not know how to display the read in text in the GUI. Below is my code. When I run it displays the GUI but does not display the read in text.

```
public class ASSIGNMENT {

    private JLabel lbl1;
    private JTextField txt1;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JFrame frame;

    public ASSIGNMENT(){
        createGUI();
        addLabels();

        frame.add(panel); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createGUI(){ 
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Books");
        frame.setSize(730, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBounds(10, 10, 10, 10);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder (Color.decode("#1854A2"), 2));
        frame.add(panel);
    }

    public void addLabels(){
        lbl1 = new JLabel(" ");
        lbl1.setBounds(700, 450, 120, 25);
        lbl1.setForeground(Color.white);
        panel.add(lbl1);
    }

    public void books() throws IOException{
        String result = "books2.txt";
        String line;
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("books2.txt")));
        while((line = lnr.readLine()) != null){
            result += line;
        }
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(result);
        panel.add(label1);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        new ASSIGNMENT();

    }
}
```

Comment: I see you have written a `books()` method to read the file and place its contents in a JLabel.  But that method won’t execute unless you actually call it from somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Hello here is your code working. You basically need to set a Layout Manager properly. You have two options. **Option one** is to have NULL and layout manager. In this case you need to position all your components with setBounds().

**Option number two** is to use a more user friendly layout manager that does not require that like GridBagLayout. Bellow you can see your code corrected for GridBagLayout. I repeat having null as manager is possible, but you need to position your elements with coordinates with the help of setBounds

```
public class ASSIGNMENT3 {

    private JLabel lbl1;
    private JTextField txt1;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JFrame frame;

    public ASSIGNMENT3() throws IOException{
        createGUI();
        addLabels();
        books();

        frame.add(panel); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createGUI(){ 
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Books");
        frame.setSize(730, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBounds(10, 10, 10, 10);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder (Color.decode("#1854A2"), 2));
        frame.add(panel);
    }

    public void addLabels(){
        lbl1 = new JLabel("Labe 1 ");
        lbl1.setBounds(700, 450, 120, 25);
        lbl1.setForeground(Color.white);
        panel.add(lbl1);
    }

    public void books() throws IOException{
        String result = "books2.txt";
        String line;
//        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("books2.txt")));
//        while((line = lnr.readLine()) != null){
//            result += line;
//        }
//        
        txt1 = new JTextField(20);
        txt1.setText(result);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(result);
        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(txt1);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        new ASSIGNMENT3();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Do you know how I can make it so each new line from the file is on a new line in the GUI?

Comment: As @NathanProgrammer mentioned already you need a JTextArea if you want to have text that spans over many lines. JTextField is juts a JTextField.

Comment: I have used a JTextArea instead of a JTextField, but am unsure of how to make it display the next line from the file on a new line in the Text Area

Comment: There you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088016/add-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-jtextarea